# Right way to use UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't get any errors yet, but I just want to know if it is "legal" to do it like this, let's consider the following example:

```
class SomeView : UIViewController { 
     var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

     @IBAction func buttonOne(sender: UIButton) {
            alertView.title = "Button Pressed 1"
            alertView.message = "Button Message 1"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()   
     }

     @IBAction func buttonOne(sender: UIButton) {
            alertView.title = "Button Pressed 2"
            alertView.message = "Button Message 2"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show() 
     }

}
```

Is this a valid way to use the `UIAlertView` or do I need to declare it each time I use it? Just to make sure this won't be a problem in the future.

Comment: @Downvoters, some comments it will be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 8 the UIAlertView is deprecated. Now UIAlertController is a single class for creating and interacting with what we knew as UIAlertView. This is the way to create it:-

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

create handler for handle the events on alert

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
    switch action.style{
    case .Default:
        println("default")
        break

    case .Cancel:
        println("cancel")
        break

    case .Destructive:
        println("destructive")
        break
    }
    }))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Courtsey:- http://ashishkakkad.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/working-with-alert-in-swift-language-ios-8-xcode-6/